# Find similar items in list of dictionaries based on values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filtering, similarity

I want to match similar articles from a django database based on tags which are stored in a list of dictionary like follows:

```
myarticle = {'pk': 17, 'tags': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]}
allarticles = [{'pk': 1, 'tags': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]}, 
               {'pk': 2, 'tags': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]},
               {'pk': 3, 'tags': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]},
               {'pk': 4, 'tags': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]},
               {'pk': 5, 'tags': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}]
```

What is the most convenient way to get a list back that ranks the number of matching tags based on the input myarticle. Expected result:

```
result = [2, 1, 3, 5, 4]
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 6):

You can use `sorted`:

```
myarticle = {'pk': 17, 'tags': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]}
allarticles = [{'pk': 1, 'tags': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]}, 
           {'pk': 2, 'tags': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]},
           {'pk': 3, 'tags': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]},
           {'pk': 4, 'tags': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]},
           {'pk': 5, 'tags': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}]
new_articles = sorted(allarticles, key=lambda x:sum(a == b for a, b in zip(myarticle['tags'], x['tags'])), reverse=True)
final_results = [i['pk'] for i in new_articles]
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 3, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use 3rd party NumPy for a vectorised solution, via `numpy.argsort`.

For larger input list, this should be more efficient:

```
allarticles = allarticles*10000

import numpy as np

def jp(myarticle, allarticles):
    arr = np.argsort((np.array([d['tags'] for d in allarticles]) == myarticle['tags']).sum(1))[::-1]
    return [allarticles[i]['pk'] for i in arr]

def ajax(myarticle, allarticles):
    new_articles = sorted(allarticles, key=lambda x:sum(a == b for a, b in zip(myarticle['tags'], x['tags'])), reverse=True)
    return [i['pk'] for i in new_articles]

%timeit jp(myarticle, allarticles)    # 49.3 ms per loop
%timeit ajax(myarticle, allarticles)  # 112 ms per loop
```